# Input with Datalist - ng-change is not fired in IE for AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I have an input tag with datalist for which the ng-change is not getting fired on selection in Internet Explorer 11. It only gets fired on blur of the input. It  is working in Chrome.

Codepen Below:
 https://codepen.io/vijayvmenon/pen/gzLYgp

```
<input list="testList" name="origin node" ng-model="SelectedDoctor" 
       ng-change="LoadSessionData(SelectedDoctor)" 
       autocomplete="off" required /> 
<datalist id="testList" > 
   <option value={{value.id}} ng-repeat="value in data"> 
</datalist>
  <p>{{selectedVal}}</p>
```

If you check the code, you can see that in chrome  the data list value is shown below on selection. In IE , the value is shown only on tab key press or when we click outside the tag.

Please let me know how I can get this working in IE, so that the ng-change can be fired on selection of datalist value.

Note: If you change AngularJS version to 1.2.x, it is working fine. Anything above, its not working. This is a simplified version for a bigger application and I am triggering a backend service on selection from the datalist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option of oninput event for input field

```
<input list="testList" name="origin node" ng-model="SelectedDoctor" oninput = "angular.element(document.getElementById('check')).scope().LoadSessionData(this)" autocompletestListte="off" required /> 
<datalist id="testList" >
```

ng-change is not fired because of the datalist on which ng-click or ng-change doesn't work

After assigning value to scope variable - selectedVal , run $scope.$apply() to see the selected option on the UI

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/jxVOrp

Comment: Thank you Naga Sai. This works as expected! Appreciate your help!

Comment: I do not recommend mixing native JavaScript event handlers such as `oninput` and AngularJS callbacks!

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS ignores the `input` event in Internet Explorer 11, because Microsoft's support for `input` is very buggy. However, you could implement your own directive and assign it to the element, in order to emit a `change` event yourself, whenever an `input` event occurs.

```
.directive('input', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on('input', function() { element.triggerHandler('change'); });
    }
  };
});
```

I do not recommend using the `oninput` attribute, because you should always stick with the `ng-*` attributes and not mix up AngularJS callbacks and native JavaScript event handlers. Using `oninput`, you might end up with other problems concerning the AngularJS data model.