# AngularJS <datalist> giving weird options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-datalist

I'm trying to convert this:

```
<td class="col-md-2">
<select style="max-width:120px" 
        ng-model="row.gaProfileId" 
        ng-repeat="profile.id as weGaAdminCtrl.showProfile(profile) for profile in weGaAdminCtrl.profiles"
        ng-change="weGaAdminCtrl.assignBrandToProfile(row)">
        </select>
</td>
```

into something like this:

```
<td class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" list="datalist">
      <datalist id="datalist">
        <select style="max-width:120px;" 
                ng-model='row.gaProfileId' 
                ng-options='profile.id as weGaAdminCtrl.showProfile(profile) for profile in weGaAdminCtrl.profiles'
                ng-change="weGaAdminCtrl.assignBrandToProfile(row)">
        </select>
      </datalist>
</td>
```

What I get is this:
[Datalist preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEigF.png)

[image]

Now what I don't get is how it gives me "string:###". Does anyone know how I can alter this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*html :*

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

   <input list="trees" name ="trees">
<datalist id="trees">
//<select> is optional 
  <option ng-repeat="tree in trees" value="{{tree.name}}">{{tree.name}}</option>
//</select>
</datalist>


</div>
```

*js :*

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.trees = [
  {'name':'oak'},
  {'name':'ash'},
  {'name':'fir'}
];
}
```

To fire `ng-change` from *datalist* in Angular 1.x read **[Input with Datalist - ng-change is not fired in IE for AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50054447/input-with-datalist-ng-change-is-not-fired-in-ie-for-angularjs/50068486)** and **https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3036**

And because of styling `datalist` and `select` see [Is it possible to style the drop-down suggestions when using HTML5 <datalist>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062414/is-it-possible-to-style-the-drop-down-suggestions-when-using-html5-datalist)