# Number input with datalist does not trigger change event

Tags: html, angularjs, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, html-input

I am using an input field of type `number` with a list of suggestions defined as a `datalist`.

Internet Explorer 11 and Microsoft Edge do not trigger the change event, once a suggestion is picked from the list. Neither the `ng-model` will update, nor will `ng-change` be triggered. It works fine in other browsers, though.

```
<input type="number" list="suggestions" ng-model="selectedValue" />

<datalist id="suggestions">
  <option value="0.5"></option>
  <option value="1"></option>
  <option value="1.5"></option>
  <option value="2"></option>
</datalist>

{{ selectedValue | json }}
```

Microsoft's browsers behave differently: One of them will update the model, when user clicks outside of the input field and it looses focus. The other browser will not trigger a change event at all. Entering values manually (by keyboard, not selecting a suggestion) will always update the model.

**Is there anything I can do about that?** Either a workaround, or, maybe am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to test the `oninput`event for the input field. See whether it helps to fix the issue.

example:

```
<input list="testList" name="origin node" ng-model="SelectedDoctor" oninput = "angular.element(document.getElementById('check')).scope().LoadSessionData(this)" autocompletestListte="off" required /> 
<datalist id="testList" >
```

Reference:

[Input with Datalist - ng-change is not fired in IE for AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50068486/10309381)